# Dice game: keep individual dice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, dice

i'm quite new to objective-c programming but building my own dice roll game helped me understanding the basics of it. I know there are a lot of topics on dice roll games here but didn't find what I'm looking for.
I've created a game  with 8 different dice (all in a separate image view) that use a random generated number from 1 to 6. The player can roll all the dice with one tap and a label is updated with the total amount of points in each roll. However, to improve a score I want to enable the player to keep a certain die after a roll (by tapping the individual die) and continue with the others.
I've implemented a log that shows if a certain die is tapped, as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

UITapGestureRecognizer *recogDice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
[self.firstDieView addGestureRecognizer:recogDice]; 
}

-(void)tapRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"Nr 1 touched"); 
}
```

Of course, this indeed shows me that the die is tapped, but I don't know how to code it from here so that the die in fact will not roll when the others get rolled again.
My code for rolling is as follows:

```
-(void)throw {
DiceThrowController *diceController = [[DiceThrowController alloc] init];

int firstNumber = [diceController getDieNumber]; //for this example i've cut out the other dice, which are the same as this one, only called 'second' etc.

[self.firstDieView showDieNumber:firstNumber];

self.sumLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", firstNumber];
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? My game works perfectly but I want to add some actual interaction / goal to it. Thanks

Comment: Does each dice-view have its own diceThrowController instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dice is a clear an object as you'll ever see so it would make a lot of sense to create a Dice class.

Personally I would probably have the following public properties for the class:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL locked;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentValue;
```

and possibly an imageView for display purposes.
I would personally have the logic "spinning" the dice as a method in the dice class:

```
-(void)spin{
    if (!self.locked){
        // Your actual spin logic goes here
    }
};
```

and have this triggered by the tapGestureRecognizer.

The in you `DiceThrowController` you could have an `NSArray *diceSet;` including all the instances. To get the total score you'd simply iterate through the `diceSet` to aggregate the score:

```
NSInteger totalScore = 0;

for (Dice *dice in diceSet){
    totalScore += dice.currentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a NSMutableArray for saving those tapped scores. Just initialize the array with 8 zeros so you know which dice isn't tapped yet:

```
NSMutableArray diceScores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacitive:8];
[diceScores setArray:@[@0, @0, @0, @0, @0, @0, @0, @0]];
```

When a dice gets tapped just save the score in the array at the corresponding index (so first dice at index 0, ...) with `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`

But be warned, this solution needs you to change your api a bit. Since you can't save ints in an array but only objects you should change your `getDieNumber` so that it returns a `NSNumber` instead of an int.